# Pgfplots surface does not hide background marker

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a function over a triangle, so first I add the triangular base over which the function is nonzero. Then I add nodes at the triangle corners. Finally, I add the function (linear in this case). However, as you can see in the figure, the background marker is not hidden behind the plotted surface (and the triangular base is!). Is there a way to hide this marker that (not adding the marker is not an option). This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
        variable=s,
        variable y=t,        
        axis line style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        ]
        
\def\triangleParamX{s)}
\def\triangleParamY{t*(1-s)}

% draw triangle
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1, color=gray, opacity=1, fill opacity=1, draw opacity=0, faceted color=black, samples=2] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY,{0});

% add nodes
\addplot3[mark=*] 
coordinates {
    (0,0,0) % first corner
    (1,0,0) % second corner
    (0,1,0) % second corner
    (0,0,0) % first corner
};

% draw surface
\addplot3[surf,domain=0:1, samples=20] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY, {y});
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Why is it not an option simply not to plot what you do not want?

Comment: Because part of that circle has to be visible when I plot other functions.

Comment: Why do you not accept and upvote the answers you receive?

Comment: Because your answer didn't work out for me. I had to ditch marks completely and go with just drawing on the plane circles first.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
set layers, mark layer=like plot,
clip=false,
variable=s,
variable y=t,        
hide axis,
]
\def\triangleParamX{s)}
\def\triangleParamY{t*(1-s)}
\addplot3[surf, shader=flat, gray, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1, samples=2] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY,{0});
\addplot3[mark=*] coordinates{
(0,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(0,1,0)
} -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1, samples=20] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY, {y});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shaded triangle and partly visible points]

Comment: This solution seems to work but apparently not within a `\begin{scope}` environment, it's like the coordinates of the scope are not accounted for. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: What does "the coordinates of the scope" mean? A scope does not have coordinates.

Comment: This figure is part of a more complex figure where I have multiple `\begin{scope}` environments. For instance, if you put this figure within an environment `\begin{scope}[shift={(4,-4)},yscale=1,xscale=1}]`, then no matter what you put within the shift parameter, the function will always appear in the same location.

Comment: With layers it is not allowed to to put `axis` in a scope. You can just move the `axis` with e.g. `\begin{axis}[anchor=origin, at={(4cm,-4cm)}, ...`

Comment: This doesn't work still, lots of issues positioning groupplot and also adding other scopes, for instance adding backgrounds referring to locations in the plot that uses layers, doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve my issue by just plotting without marks (circles on the plane):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
        variable=s,
        variable y=t,        
        axis line style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        clip=false
        ]
        
\def\triangleParamX{s)}
\def\triangleParamY{t*(1-s)}

% draw triangle
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1, color=gray, opacity=1, fill opacity=1, draw opacity=0, faceted color=black, samples=2] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY,{0});

% add nodes
\addplot3[mark=none] 
coordinates {
    (0,0,0) % first corner
    (1,0,0) % second corner
    (0,1,0) % second corner
    (0,0,0) % first corner
};

\draw[fill=black] (5,0,0) arc (0:360:5);
\draw[fill=black] (105,0,0) arc (0:360:5);
\draw[fill=black] (5,100,0) arc (0:360:5);


% draw surface
\addplot3[surf,domain=0:1, samples=20] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY, {y});
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]