# Surface mesh plot with lower-sample mesh

Tags: pgfplots

I have a very nonlinear function for which I need a high sample number. However, with this sample number the mesh is too fine. I was wondering whether it is possible to create a surface plot where the function is plotted using a high sample rate, but the mesh is plotted as if I had used a low sample rate. I think this would also help with the coloring, since using a low sample rate draws the patches with a single color (so the plot doesn't seem to be continuous). This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colormap/viridis,
        width=176.68246pt,
        zlabel={$u$},
        axis lines*=left,
        view={15}{30},
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xmin=0,xmax=1,
        ymin=0,ymax=1,
        xtick={0,1},
        ytick={0,1},
%       ztick={0},
        every axis z label/.style={at={(current axis.west)},xshift=-5pt, yshift=30pt,rotate=0}
    ]
     \addplot3[surf,samples=40, domain=0:0.5, y domain=0:1] { 100*x*(1-4*x)*(5-4*x)*(1-2*x)/6  };
     \addplot3[surf,samples=40, domain=0.5:1, y domain=0:1] { 100*(3-4*x)*(1-2*x)*(1-x)*(1+4*x)/6  };
    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems if the surface is plotted using a high sample rate, then the mesh with low sample rate will diverge from the surface. The discrete colormap may be helpful for your purpose `\begin{axis}[colormap={cmap}{samples of colormap=(7 of viridis)}, colormap access=piecewise constant, ... `. Also, use `shader=flat` option for the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading, line join=round]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=none,
view={15}{30},
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
\addplot3[surf, faceted color=transparent!0, fill=transparent!100, domain=0:0.5, samples=17, domain y=0:1, samples y=9, forget plot] { 100*x*(1-4*x)*(5-4*x)*(1-2*x)/6 };
\addplot3[surf, faceted color=transparent!0, fill=transparent!100, domain=0.5:1, samples=17, domain y=0:1, samples y=9, forget plot] { 100*(3-4*x)*(1-2*x)*(1-x)*(1+4*x)/6 };
\end{axis}
\path (0,0) circle[radius=10]; %encompassing circle for alignment
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
colormap/viridis,
view={15}{30},
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
\addplot3[surf, shader=interp, samples=60, domain=0:0.5, y domain=0:1, samples y=2] { 100*x*(1-4*x)*(5-4*x)*(1-2*x)/6 };
\addplot3[surf, shader=interp, samples=60, domain=0.5:1, y domain=0:1, samples y=2] { 100*(3-4*x)*(1-2*x)*(1-x)*(1+4*x)/6 };
\end{axis}
\fill[path fading=myfading, fit fading=false, opacity=0.3] (0,0) rectangle (7,7); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A surface plot with a coarse mesh]

Comment: Could you please explain your answer? it seems you're plotting twice? Would the produced file take more memory?

Comment: Yes I am per request plotting twice. One time for the (high resolution) surface and one time for the (low resolution) mesh. With the "low resolution" mesh on top of the "high resolution" surface, it all looks "low resolution", so I question the efficacy of the method for this particular surface/function. By "memory" do you mean disk space? -yes adding an extra mesh will use a little more space -you can use a file browser to check. My code use significantly less space than your code as the surface only needs `samples y=2`.

Comment: So there isn't a possibility to plot a high-resolution mesh with a small number of lines? Isn't the creation of isolines exactly trying to do this for other types of plots?

Comment: I just noticed the code doesn't work with externalize, I believe because you're referring to the name `myfading`. Is there a workaround without having to disable externalize?

Comment: I do not use externalise myself, so I can not answer.

Comment: You ask one question and refuse to accept the answer you receive because it does not fulfil a secret requirement. Please accept the answer and ask a new question about the new problem. Stop moving the goal post. You did the same thing here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667727/8650.

Comment: In that post you mentioned I actually ended up answering my own question. I did’t refuse your answer, I just didn’t think about it. I believe people reply to a question because they want to help, not because of the reward.

Comment: @aaragon: An upvote and acceptance of an answer is obviously not any form of reward. -it is a clean way for OP to show appreciation. It is very annoying to use time on an answer and then never hear anything from OP. You have many questions with two or three unaccepted answers.